# Fit a set of rectangular blocks given in a random order into a minimum volume box

Tags: permutations, combinatorial-geometry, packing-problem

Given a set of blocks whose length, width, and height respectively are $A:1 \times 3 \times 2$, $B: 2 \times 2 \times 1$, $C \text{ and } D: 2 \times 1 \times 1$, and $E,F,G\text{ and }H: 1 \times 1 \times 1$. The blocks can be rotated in any direction, but cannot be replaced once laid down.

If we have control over the order of the blocks handed to us, we can for example stack all boxes into a $3 \times 3 \times 2$ box, as shown in the picture below, an optimal solution:
[image: An optimal packing of the 8 boxes]
Now assume that we have no control over the order of the blocks handed to us, and we cannot move blocks once placed, what is the smallest volume box that guarantees to fit all the blocks? An obvious upper bound is to place all boxes in one layer, but this will result in too much wasted space.

It might also be too difficult to find the exact smallest volume, but any solution improved upon the obvious upper bound is welcomed.

My intuition is that you need to divide the blocks into a few groups, the placement of each group is independent of the other groups, and inside each groups, the total occupied space is the same for any ordering within the group. One such group could be $C$ and $D$, since the volume from stacking these $2$ is the same regardless of which appears first.

Updates:
Inspired by the accepted answer, I found those optimal solutions to the problem:

1. Sort the items into stack height of 1:

AADDCF

AABBCG

AABBEH

2. Sort the items into stack height of 2:

See the accepted answer

3. Sort the items into stack height of 3:

Assume stacked product of BC = X, stacked product of DG = Y, stacked product of EFH = Z

AXY

AXZ

4. Sort the items into stack of height>3:

Obviously, to achieve an optimal solution, the stack height can only be 6,9 and 18.

Stack height of 6:
Combine ABC, and DEFGH

Stack height of 9:
Not possible

Stack height of 18:
Not possible

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: the only problem figures in the B fragment when given to us later.

Comment: which means, the minimum volume is 3*3*3

Comment: @Abra001, in this specific case, that's correct.

Comment: @Abra001, I believe I had 3*3*2, which describe the volume of the stacked blocks shown in the picture above.

Comment: @Susie yes, only when you have control over ordering, or when you can delay the action of stacking each one ahead the other.

Comment: Your question is not totally well-defined, in my opinion. For the particular set of blocks you give, Mike Earnest's answer solves the problem for many possible interpretations of your question, so IMO you should accept his answer. The ambiguities in your question are: (1) *exactly* what types of movements of the blocks are acceptable, (2) where and in what orientation do they start, and (3) does the box itself pose a barrier to the movement of the blocks (e.g., are all sides of the box impenetrable except an open top side). Is this some kind of 3D Tetris puzzle?

Comment: @RonKaminsky, thank you for reminding me. I now realize I didn't understand Mike's answer because in my mind I defined the problem in a different way then Mike understood. I will remove my original constraints so that you can place the blocks anyway you want, except to move it after it has been placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am interpreting the problem incorrectly, but I think you can always achieve an optimal packing. To do so, build this arrangement, which has a height of $2$, and where the X's refer to stacks of two $1 \times 1 ×1$  blocks.

```
A C D
A X B
A X B
```

Every block touches the floor, so every block can be placed when it is handed to you (except for the top blocks atop the two X towers, but these are placed on top of the previous small blocks).

Comment: Hi Mike, I am not sure If I understand your answer entirely, my interpretation is that assuming the stacked product of C&D is Y.  The following configuration is always achievable: line 1: A Y Y line2: AXBB, line3: AXBB, therefore contained in a box volume of 3*4*2?

Comment: I understand your solution now! It is an excellent answer given that the boxes can be flipped, however my intension was that only rotation along Z axis is allowed, therefore B and C,D cannot be stood up. But I will still accept your answer as it provide good insights that the blocks should be divided into exchangeable stacks with a height of 2.

Comment: @Susie ooooh I understand my misunderstanding. I will think some more about this